# Is there a name for this type of progress bar at the top of screens?

Tags: gui-design, progress-bar, loading

[image]
[image]

Lots of applications and sites (particularly SPAs or sites with lots of data to load such as YouTube) have a progress bar that is displayed at the very top of the screen.

Does this have a special name?

Comment: Preloaders (or progress indicators) are interface elements that let users know that the website hasn’t crashed, it’s just processing data.

Answer (score 7):

According to Material.io, these UI elements are called [progress indicators](https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html):

> Progress indicators inform users about the status of ongoing
>   processes, such as loading an app, submitting a form, or saving
>   updates. They communicate an app’s state and indicate available
>   actions, such as whether users can navigate away from the current
>   screen.

Answer (score 3):

That's a [progress indicator](https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html).

I think Flickr might be the first one start using this in early days, that will be back at least 10 years ago, then Material design release an official doc and usage for this.

Comment: It goes to show that certain design trends/patterns emerge and disappear in cycles :)

Answer (score 2):

Sitepoint called it "Progress Loading Line". 
 Which seems like specific, "progress indicator" is general term.

https://www.sitepoint.com/5-progress-loading-lines-youtube-style-jquery-plugins/